# Save data entered in a form with CKEditor to MySQL database

Tags: jquery, mysql, symfony, ckeditor

I have a HTML form, the image of which is displayed below.

[image]

When the user clicks on the "Add Content" button, I want the data entered in the form saved to the MySQL database. Mathematical Equations too can be entered by a user.

The editor used is CKEditor.
Development framework is Symfony2.

I am using a jQuery event handler to pass the contents of the form to my controller.
Also, please could you guide me on how can I display the data in a HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var val= CKEDITOR.instances['youreditorid'].getData();
```

this may help you.

Comment: I was able to save the entry to the database. I want to display the data in a HTML page with all the formatting used in the editor. How do I do that?

Comment: Which templating engine you are using? Twig?

Comment: @Ramesh yes..i am using twig.

Comment: are you `encoding` the values while you save ? then try to `decode` it using `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: @Ramesh I have not done any encoding. I am simply fetching the data from the database in my controller, passing it to my template. So how do I display the data.

Comment: @Lumiere I don't know much about twig use `raw` keyword `{{ word | raw }}` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension

Comment: @Ramesh please help..!!

Comment: @Lumiere if this answer fix your problem don't forget mark it as answer. So that helps others

Comment: @Ramesh anyways.it served my purpose..!

Answer (score 0):

In twig, you can set up the escaping strategies. If you want to print the entered data as it is without escaping, you can use,

```
{{ user_html | raw}}
```

in Twig.

However, this is vulnerable to XSS. So better use 'js' escaping:

```
{{ user_html | escape('js') }}
```